# How to eliminate nothing elements in a array (1D) in Julia?

Tags: julia

I would like to know how I could eliminate nothing elements in a Julia array (1D) like the one below. It was built from reading a text file with lines with no relevant information mixed with lines with relevant information. "nothing" is type Void and I would like to clean the array of all of it.

```
nothing                                                                                                                                 
nothing                                                                                                                                 
nothing                                                                                                                                 
nothing                                                                                                                                 
nothing                                                                                                                                 
"   -16.3651\t     0.1678\t    -4.6997\t   -14.0152\t    -2.6855\t   -16.0294\t    -7.8049\t   -27.1912\t    -5.0354\t   -14.5187\t\r\n"
"   -16.4490\t    -1.0910\t    -3.6087\t   -12.6724\t    -1.5945\t   -14.7705\t    -7.2174\t   -25.2609\t    -3.7766\t   -14.3509\t\r\n"
"   -16.4490\t    -2.2659\t    -2.4338\t   -10.9100\t    -0.5875\t   -13.6795\t    -6.7139\t   -22.9950\t    -2.9373\t   -14.0991\t\r\n"
```

Comment: as @Ismael mentioned if you are trying to read a tabbed separated matrix  of data, first clean your data (with a text editor like notepad++) then use `readdlm` to load them into a matrix

Comment: @RezaAfzalan: Thank you for your comment. The point is that I have more than 100 files to read, each of them with more than 35k lines, with mixed line sizes (relevant lines are mixed with small length lines (irrelevant)). To previously edit each file seems not practical for my situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you reading that file?

You can filter out `nothing`'s from an array:

```rb
filter(x -> !isnothing(x), [nothing, 42]) # => Any[42]
```

But you may want to clean your data first, with a tab separated values (.tsv) file like this:

```rb
-16.3651    0.1678  -4.6997 -14.0152    -2.6855 -16.0294    -7.8049 -27.1912    -5.0354 -14.5187
-16.4490    -1.0910 -3.6087 -12.6724    -1.5945 -14.7705    -7.2174 -25.2609    -3.7766 -14.3509
-16.4490    -2.2659 -2.4338 -10.9100    -0.5875 -13.6795    -6.7139 -22.9950    -2.9373 -14.0991
```

Using `readdlm`:

```rb
julia> readdlm("data.tsv")
3x10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -16.3651   0.1678  -4.6997  -14.0152  …  -27.1912  -5.0354  -14.5187
 -16.449   -1.091   -3.6087  -12.6724     -25.2609  -3.7766  -14.3509
 -16.449   -2.2659  -2.4338  -10.91       -22.995   -2.9373  -14.0991
```

Using `DataFrmaes.readtable`:

```rb
julia> df = readtable("data.tsv");

julia> names!(df, [symbol(x) for x in 'A':'J'])
2x10 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | A       | B       | C       | D        | E       | F        | G       |
|-----|---------|---------|---------|----------|---------|----------|---------|
| 1   | -16.449 | -1.091  | -3.6087 | -12.6724 | -1.5945 | -14.7705 | -7.2174 |
| 2   | -16.449 | -2.2659 | -2.4338 | -10.91   | -0.5875 | -13.6795 | -6.7139 |

| Row | H        | I       | J        |
|-----|----------|---------|----------|
| 1   | -25.2609 | -3.7766 | -14.3509 |
| 2   | -22.995  | -2.9373 | -14.0991 |
```

Comment: Thank you @Ismael. Of course reading the file as TSV would work better, but the line size (and data) is not uniform so some rows would have less data than others. Would it work with readtable or readdlm?

Comment: I have tried and it reads the TSV file, adding "" to "missing" values (it was new for me). I got rid of almost all irrelevant lines. Trying to eliminate non numerical lines now. Any tip?

Comment: One way would be, for an array `v`: `[typeof(x) <: Number for x in v]` or the same but using `filter`

Comment: @RgrNormand I highly recommend you tu use some methodology like [CRISP-DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Industry_Standard_Process_for_Data_Mining), since the **Data Preparation** process is specially time consuming.

Answer (score 6):

`testvector[testvector.!=nothing]` is also a very readable option.

benchmarking can help choose the most efficient code.

Answer (score 4):

one simple way is using `filter!` function to update your vector like this:

```
testvector=[fill(nothing,10) ; [1,2,3]];
# =>13-element Array{Any,1}:
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    nothing
#    1
#    2
#    3

filter!(x->x!=nothing, testvector)
# => 3-element Array{Any,1}:
#     1
#     2
#     3
```

thanks @Daniel Arndt

EDIT, Refer to this paragraph from Julia doc:

> `nothing` is a special value that does not print anything at the
>   interactive prompt. Other than not printing, **it is a completely normal
>   value and you can test for it programmatically.**

I think all of the conditions below, reach us to the same result

```
x!=nothing
x!==nothing
!is(x,nothing)
!isa(x,Void)
typeof(x)!=Void
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the typeof function over something like ```filter!(x->x!=nothing,testvector)```?

Comment: @DanielArndt You should use `!==` which checks the type. There is a slight performance issue with using a lambda, but IMO not worth worrying about.

Comment: Here to eliminate an element it's enough to have the type of `Void`, so it's the minimal condition, and probably more efficient, but in my option `x!=nothing` is simpler and more concrete.

Comment: Notice that the resulting array is of type `Any`, you may want to `Int[filter!(x -> x != nothing, testvector)...]`, but obviously they way he's reading the data is wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and help. I am experimenting with Julia to improve performance over R. Probably making many mistakes, but learning a lot. Adding more info, the file is a text file (.dat) with mixed line sizes - some short (irrelevant) and some long (with relevant data). Reading as a TSV may not work as size lines are not constant. Am I wrong with that assumption?

Comment: @RezaAfzalan Thank you for the nothing highlight. I have not caught the "a completely normal value" point before.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers above, it appears:

```
filter(!isnothing, [nothing, 42])
```

is a working shorthand for `filter(x -> !isnothing(x), [nothing, 42])`, and will correctly return `42`.

Answer (score 0):

Dear All,

At the end, the code became this:

```
tmpFile=open(fileName)
tmp=readdlm(tmpFile);
ind=pmap(typeof,tmp[:,1]).!=SubString{ASCIIString}; # if the first column typeof is string, than pmap will return false, else, it return true. This will provide an index of valid/not valid rows.
tmpClean=tmp[ind,:]; # only valid rows will be used
```

If you may have any suggestion to improve it, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: how are this files generated? Wouldn't it be better to do this validation only once (read non valid files, validate, write validated file), instead of each time you load your data?

Comment: Thank you @IsmaelVenegasCastelló. It was my first idea to read all/check/write correct lines. It seems to me your suggestion and mine produce equivalent results (despite mine is not showing the writing part. Am I correct?